# Phonegap 3 - How to call Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm using phonegap 3 and I'm unable to call my functions, it doesen't work !

This is my code it's a basic sample for create contacts, but I won't to create a bunch of buttons to do different things like create, delete list and stuff like this but I can't get with it. The only code executed is in the inside of "OnDeviceReady" function.

How can i call my functions and how ? Because the basic Javascript doesen't run. Thanks !

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>PILLEpalle!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
            <div id="contactcreated" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Creating Contact</p>
                <p class="event received">Contact created</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My js file

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "Test User"});
        myContact.note = "This contact has a note.";
        console.log("The contact, " + myContact.displayName + ", note: " + myContact.note);
        app.receivedEvent('contactcreated');
        myContact.save(app.onContactSaveSuccess,app.onContactSaveError);
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    onContactSaveSuccess: function(contact) {
        window.alert("Save Success");
    },
    onContactSaveError: function(contact) {
        window.alert("Save Failed");
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seens like you need some reading on POO: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming

Basically, the functions you've created inside the var app scope you call like this: app.myFunction();

If you want then to be called when a device event occurs, then you need to add then as a listener to the device events. Take a look at the docs: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events

Comment: I developed POO but not in cordova and I'm a bit lost with this, there are an easyer way of handle functions ? Could you gave me an example? Thanks

Comment: You can simple create your function on your index.js file like: function myFunction();  and call it on an button click.. It's like a normal website!

Comment: You don't really need the events, but it's a better pratice

Comment: Thanks budd, Don't tell me why but I started using the code inside de app var and wasn't necessary, thanks !